# Is it true that calling this() inside a constructor implicitly calls super()?

Tags: java, class, constructor

I was trying to understand

**why this() and super() cant be used together?**

I have read many of the related discussions here on stackoverflow and got many things understood. But just one confusion I still have is.

> calling this() inside a constructor implicitly calls super()

consider this code..

```
class Top
{
    int z;
    Top()
    {
        System.out.println("Top default constructor");
    }

}
class A extends Top
{
    int x;
    A(int num)
    {
        x=num;
        System.out.println("A parameterized constructor");
    }
    A()
    {
        this(5);
        System.out.println("A default constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        new A();
    }
}
```

and OUTPUT is :

> Top default constructor
>
> A parametrized constructor
>
> A default constructor

I was not expecting the first line in output "*Top default constructor*" as there is no super() call, implicit or explicit.

So there is, probably, something which I misunderstood. Please explain.

Comment: Simpe rule: The first statement in a constructor must be a call to another constructor - either in the same class (`this(...)`) or in the parent class (`super(...)`). If you omit an explicit constructor call, the compiler will automatically generate an implicit call to `super()` - the no-arg parent constructor - as the first statement.

Comment: Actually, there is an implicit super() call. It is not explicitly written down but it is implied (by the standard)

Comment: Warning! The 'default constructor' is the implicit constructor added by the compiler in a class when there is no explicit constructor inside this class. If you add a constructor in a class, the implicit one disapear. Top(){} and A(){} are not default constructors,there are none argument constructors, is different! The default constructor has the same access modifier as the class, no-args and has super() at his first line. You cannot see it, it added at the compilation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `this()` inside a constructor invokes another constructor of the same class. The other constructor would call the `super()` constructor (implicitly or explicitly), which is why you can't call both `this()` and `super()` in the same constructor, as that would result in two `super()` constructors being called.

Note that whenever I write `this()` or `super()` I don't necessarily mean calls to a parameter-less constructor (except for the implicit call to `super()` which is always to the parameter-less constructor of the super class, as commented by Joeblade). Both calls can have parameters.

In your code sample, `A()` constructor calls `A(int)` constructor (that's what `this(5)` does), which calls `Top()` (parameter-less) constructor implicitly.

Comment: Good answer, but super() is actually specifically the constructor without arguments, when it is implicitly called. Any other use must be explicitly called.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it true that calling this() inside a constructor implicitly calls super()?

Calling `this()` in a constructor will call the zero-args constructor for that class. If the zero-args constructor for that class doesn't have an explicit call to `super(...)`, then yes, there will be an *implicit* call to the zero-args `super()` constructor. If the zero-args constructor in your class has an explicit call to some other `super` signature, then of course that's done instead.

This is true for constructors in general. In your `A` class, since your `A(int)` constructor doesn't have any call to `this()` *or* `super()`, the implicit `super()` is done.

> I was not expecting the first line in output "Top default constructor" as there is no `super()` call,implicit or explicit.

Yes, there is — an implicit one. :-)

The fundamental rule is this: *Some* base class constructor must be run prior to code in the derived class running. That's why calls to `this(...)` or `super(...)` must be the *first* thing in a constructor. If a constructor doesn't have an explicit call to `super(...)`, there's always an implicit call to `super()` (with no args).

Answer (score 2):

`this(5)` calls `A(int num)` which calls `super()` implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the Java Language Specification section on [Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), with the emphasis on the superclass constructor marked in bold:

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this), then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). **If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps**. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

So in your case, when the constructor `A(int num)` is invoked using `this(5)`, step 3 indicates that it implicitly invokes the superclass constructor, applying the same procedure recursively.

Note that you can follow with the procedure by debugging the sequence of constructor calls.